# Авторизация в Spring Security с БД

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security

Как настроить авторизацию пользователей, получая данные из БД?

Предположим, я зарегистрировался, после чего хочу перейти на другую страницу. Меня перекидывает на `/login`. Ввожу данные и выходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также вылетает ошибка в консоль:

**PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select username, password from users where username=?]; Индекс колонки вне диапазона: 3. Допустимые значения: 1..2**

Ставил вместо `username=?` - `username=user`, и при регистрации вводил `user`.

Ничего не помогает.

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager users(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager users = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
        users.setUsersByUsernameQuery("select username, password from users where username=?");
        return users;
    }
}
```

*Версия Spring - 3.1.0

База Данных - Postgresql*

Answer (score 0):

Реализация JdbcUserDetailsManager ожидает три столбца в таблице users: имя пользователя, пароль и enabled, который вы можете использовать для деактивации пользователя.
Запрос по умолчанию - `DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY`; при изменении этого запроса убедитесь, что все возвращаемые столбцы отображаются на те же позиции столбцов, что и в запросе по умолчанию.
`select username,password,'true' as enabled from users where username = ?`